# Formal parameter "IV_SPECIAL_FUND_RED" does not exist after note 2443042

Tags: parameters, abap, sap-erp

I wanted to apply the note [2443042 - NT 2016-002: Solution for Condition Based Technique (CBT)](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2443042), but I can't because the class CL_TAX_CALC_BR is inactive, there is the error "Formal parameter "IV_SPECIAL_FUND_RED" does not exist" in line 42 of method CALCULATE_ICMS_PARTILHA of class CL_TAX_CALC_BR:

```
cl_j_1b_icms_partilha=>calculate(
  EXPORTING
    iv_gross_price       = lv_gross_price
    iv_special_fund_red  = ms_tax_data-icmsspecfundbase
    iv_special_fund_rate = ms_tax_data-icmsspecfundrate
    iv_orig_icms_red     = ms_tax_data-icmsbase
    iv_orig_icms_rate    = lv_icmsrate
    iv_orig_icms_amount  = lv_icmsamt
    iv_dest_icms_red     = ms_tax_data-icmsbase_intra
    iv_dest_icms_rate    = ms_tax_data-icmsrate_intra
    iv_exemption         = ms_tax_data-icmspartilhaexempt         "2283474
    is_komk              = is_komk
    is_komp              = is_komp
    it_komv              = it_komv
  IMPORTING
    ev_special_fund_base    = ms_tax_result-icms_spec_fund_base
    ev_special_fund_ebase   = ms_tax_result-icms_spec_fund_ebas   "2283474
    ev_special_fund_rate    = ms_tax_result-icms_spec_fund_rate
    ev_special_fund_amount  = ms_tax_result-icms_spec_fund_amt
    ev_orig_partilha_base   = ms_tax_result-icms_orig_part_base
    ev_orig_partilha_ebase  = ms_tax_result-icms_orig_part_exc    "2273938
    ev_orig_partilha_rate   = ms_tax_result-icms_orig_part_rate
    ev_orig_partilha_amount = ms_tax_result-icms_orig_part_amt
    ev_dest_partilha_base   = ms_tax_result-icms_dest_part_base
    ev_dest_partilha_ebase  = ms_tax_result-icms_dest_part_exc    "2273938
    ev_dest_partilha_rate   = ms_tax_result-icms_dest_part_rate
    ev_dest_partilha_amount = ms_tax_result-icms_dest_part_amt
).
```

I already searched for possible solutions within SAP support portal but the note [2524708 - Formal parameter "IV_SPECIAL_FUND_RED" does not exist](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2524708) recommends to install the note 2443042 above to solve the problem, which in fact I can't apply as I explained.

I think either there is a necessary note that either hasn't been implemented or wrongly implemented but I'm not sure.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Same issue as the one you previously posted about the different number of parameters? Did you activate all includes at the same time?

Comment: Please provide the SAP note number and the signature of method CL_J_LB_ICMS_PARTILHA=>CALCULATE

Comment: Hello Sandra, yes I acctivated it all at the same time and the problem persisted.

Comment: The note number is 2443042

Comment: Simply edit your post to include the details, don't add them into comments (limited length and only on one line). Also read the Help Center how to ask, and other rules. Well, if you look at the note 2443042, you can see that your screenshot represents the code before it's changed, can you explain? Moreover, it's a very complex note, did you read carefully its installation procedure, and the ones of all its prerequisite notes? (because there are often manual steps). Also, before applying notes, it's best to make sure that you have the latest patches for the note assistant.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. yes I haven't implemented the note due to the errors it presented It is a very complex note. But i did read the instalation procedure and made shure the pre requisite notes are correctly implemented, will check the latest patches for the asistant though.

Comment: There's the note [2524708 - Formal parameter "IV_SPECIAL_FUND_RED" does not exist](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2524708). Make sure to check the notes before posting in stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: Thanks but if you read the note it literally says to implement the note i am trying to implement to solve the exact problem I have. I did investigate throughly before posting in here.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer without knowledge of what contain the notes you are currently implementing, but if I understand well there would be too many of them (the "Legal Technical Note NT 2016-002" is a huge network of notes).

I already installed this kind of functional notes, and it's a nightmare if something goes wrong, even for experienced ABAPers.

The classic way is to analyze the technical reason of every error, and in the case of mixed notes, determine the origin of the faulty code. By the way, you didn't provide the signature of the method CALCULATE_ICMS_PARTILHA of class CL_TAX_CALC_BR, but anyway, it's obvious that a note you have applied previously has removed the parameter "IV_SPECIAL_FUND_RED". Try to find it (not easy, you'll have to identify all notes which change the class CL_TAX_CALC_BR, possibly via the SAP support portal, then look manually at the code of all these notes via the note assistant) and "deimplement" it.

If there are too many problems, it may be easier to restore the source code before you started to apply the notes, and try again. Of course, you should take notes of all the issues you have to solve, because if you fail again, it will make your next attempt "easier".

A much easier solution is to install the concerned support packages (if possible).

Comment: Yep, conflicting notes is a total mess

Comment: Thanks for the help Sandra by the way were can in find the signature I think I may be confused about them.

Comment: @JorgeEscoto The signature is simply the list of formal parameters allowed by the method (`METHODS calculate IMPORTING iv_gross_price ...`)